# MVC5 How to connect object with current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making Library using MVC and I nearly finished it all. Last thing i want to do is to let customers borrow books. In order to do that I want to find out how can I connect current logged user with certain book. I want user to be able to click on Borrow Book and he will have book available for him. Can you please explain me how may I connect these two?

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Borrow(string CustomerId, string Id)
{
    Customer customer = customerContext.Find(CustomerId);
    Book book = context.Find(Id);

    if (customer != null && book != null)
    {
        customer.borrowedBooks.Add(book);

        context.Insert(book);
        context.Commit();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
    }
    else
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}
```

Customer class:

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public List<Book> borrowedBooks { get; set; }
    public Customer() {

    }
}
```

Book class:

```
public class Book : BaseEntity
{
    [StringLength(30)]
    [DisplayName("Book Title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Writer First Name")]
    public String WriterFirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Writer Last Name")]
    public String WriterLastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Released")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Publisher")]
    public String Publisher { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Number of Books")]
    public int NumberOfBooks { get; set; }
    public String Genre { get; set; }
    public String Format { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Image { get; set; }
    public static int Count { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        
    }
}
```

IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> Collection();
    void Commit();
    void Delete(string Id);
    T Find(string Id);
    void Insert(T t);
    void Update(T t);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework , we need to config many to many relationship.
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

After that we can use : `customer.borrowedBooks.Add(book)` to add it to the many to many table.